# Mediaqueries and default function change

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I wanted to ask a question relating to a certain website functionality.

http://kccreepfest.com/

I wanted to know how this website is using a responsive design and yet maintaining it when the browser on the desktop changes.

But when opened on a mobile, a structured responsive design.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

They've got quite a bit of js going on, but for this most part, this is the key line:
    `var _isMobile = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad|android|webos)/) ? true : false;`

They're checking to see if the user agent matches iphone/ipod etc, if so, storing it in a variable, and then playing upon that to attach(or not) certain classes.